# What's wrong with this query? Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

What's wrong with this? It returns "You have an error in your syntax... ...check if you have the right MySQL version to use near 'to, content, link) VALUES..."

```
$notito = $idoftheguy;
$contentofnoti = $username." just posted a comment on your update.";
$linkofnoti = "http://mywebsite.net/post.php?id=".$thepostid;
/* Now let's insert this */
$insertnoti = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newnotifications (to, content, link) VALUES ('$notito', '$contentofnoti', '$linkofnoti')");
```

All of the above things in the query are existent in the database. And here are the exact inputs that gave the error (haven't tried any other inputs):

$notito = 1;
$contentofnoti = "Schart just posted a comment on your update.";
$linkofnoti = "http://mywebsite.net/post.php?id=22";

Comment: `to` is a MySQL reserved word, so if you use it for a table or column name you need to enclose it in backticks

Comment: Oh yeah I always forget! I've made this mistake way too many times. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned. `to` is a reserverd word. Try this code:

```
$insertnoti = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newnotifications (`to`, `content`, `link`) VALUES ('$notito', '$contentofnoti', '$linkofnoti')");
```